# How to shuffle values in an array and store shuffled values into different arrays with AVX

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, avx512

Thanks in advance for the help.  I need to be able to perform the following shuffle pattern in an array with uint16_t data.  My unprocessed array will look like the following

```
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
```

I have transformed my unprocessed data into the format below with _mm512_permutexvar_epi16

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

and then store the contents of the AVX register into 4 different arrays, this is the part I'm unsure on the best way to do.

```
next eight values of arrayofZero's 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
next eight values of arrayofOne's 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
next eight values of arrayofTwo's 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
next eight values of arrayofThree's 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

I need to loop through my unprocessed data and populate the arrayofZero's with all the 0 values and so on and so forth with my 1, 2, and 3 values.
NOTE: my actual data is not hardcoded 0, 1, 2, 3.  It is calculated data that I need to put the

```
1st value in the 1st array, 
2nd value in the 2nd array, 
3rd value in the 3rd processed data array, 
and 4th value in the 4th processed data array
```

that pattern repeats for the entire unprocessed data array. Such that after all processing is done

```
1st Array holds all the 0 values
2nd Array holds all the 1 values
3rd array holds all the 2 values
4th array holds all the 3 values
```

I have been looking at _mm512_permutexvar_epi16 to get my unprocessed data into the format.

Below is the code that I have started.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    alignas(64) std::array<uint16_t, 128> unprocessedData;
    alignas(64) std::array<uint16_t, 32> processedData0, processedData1, processedData2, processedData3; 
    alignas(64) constexpr std::array<uint16_t, 32> shuffleMask {
         0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28,
         1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29,
         2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30,
         3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31,
    };
    //prepare sample data
    for (uint16_t i {0}; i < unprocessedData.size(); i+=4)
    {
        unprocessedData[i] = 0;
        unprocessedData[i+1] = 1;
        unprocessedData[i+2] = 2;
        unprocessedData[i+3] = 3;
    } 
    for (size_t i {0}; i < unprocessedData.size(); i+=32)
    {
            auto v {_mm512_loadu_epi16(&unprocessedData[i]) };
            _mm512_storeu_epi16(&unprocessedData[i],
                                 _mm512_permutexvar_epi16(_mm512_load_si512((__m512i*)shuffleMask.data()), v));
        //Somehow Store values 0-7 of permuted array into processedData0
        //Store values 8-15 of permuted array into processedData1
        //Store values 16-23 of permuted array into processedData2
        //Store values 24-31 of permuted array into processedData3
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are there really only 4 different possible values?  Your best bet would be CountingSort (i.e. make a histogram especially on Ice Lake for fast-short-rep if that works for `rep stosw` to make N copies of a value).  Or maybe 4x compare -> 4x `vpcompressw`.

Comment: Peter, no the values can be any real number.  But those values will go into the 4 different bins.  Perhaps it would be better to label the example
UnprocessedData = a b c d e f g h i j k L
processedData1 = a e i
processedData2 = b f j
processedData3 = c g k
processedData4 = d h L

Comment: Ok, but there are only 4 bins, and you can check which bin a number should go in with what, one `cmpeq`?  Or a `cmpgt_mask` / `mask_cmple_mask` (zero-masked compare into mask) to check that `x > low && x <= high`?  Oh, `vpcompressw` is AVX512-VBMI2 (Ice Lake) :/  https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPCOMPRESS

Comment: I don't have to check what value the bin is in. I just thought of the more proper phrasing, sorry for it taking me longer to get there.  I have 4 way interleaved data in unprocessedData and what I need to do is de-interleave that data. Below would be the plain c++ of what I need to do.
`for (size_t i {0}, j {0}; i < unprocessedData.size(); i+=4, j++)
{
processedData1[j] = unprocessedData[i];
processedData2[j] = unprocessedData[i+1];
processedData3[j] = unprocessedData[i+2];processedData4[j] = unprocessedData[i+3];}`

Comment: Oh, so it's always a fixed shuffle, not value-dependent?  Yeah that's trivial.  Just `vpermw` like you're doing, and store separate parts of your vector separately.  like `_mm_storeu_si128(a0, _mm512_castsi512_si128(v))` for the low lane, then `_mm512_extracti32x4_epi32(v, 1)` to get the 2nd 128-bit chunk, etc.  Your question seemed to focus on the shuffling, not the storing.

Comment: Peter, thanks!  Sorry for the confusion, I was struggling on the storing front.  So that would take 10 AVX instructions per chunk, 1 load, 1 permute, 3 extracts, 4 stores?

Comment: 1 memory-source permute, 1 `vmovdqu` store, 3x *memory-destination* `vextracti32x4` (which doesn't involve any shuffle uops: https://uops.info/).  The compiler will take care of this for you with `tmp = extract; _mm_storeu_si128(dst, tmp);` - intrinsics might look like asm but aren't asm.

Comment: Although `vpermw zmm, zmm, [mem]` doesn't micro-fuse the load, so it costs 3 uops in the front-end, same as a separate load + permute for uop counts, only saving machine-code size.  (`vpermw` without memory is a 2-uop instruction, unfortunately, even on Ice Lake).  Hmm, might be worth doing 2x `vpermt2w` (2p05 + 4p5) to set up for 4x 256-bit stores, but that would take 2 separate shuffle control vectors.  If you had Ice Lake, it would be more efficient to use `vpermb` (1 uop for p5), because unfortunately its vpermw is still 2 uops :/  But ICL does have 2/clock store throughput.

Comment: Peter, you really know your stuff.  I know there is the intel developer's guide and architecture guide, is that where you learned all of this, or are there any more digestible sources you would recommend?

Comment: Agner Fog has a really nice table of SIMD instructions for different kinds of data-movement in the SIMD chapter of his asm optimization guide.  (https://www.agner.org/optimize/).  It mostly covers SSE last I looked at it, though, so just in-lane data movement for AVX1/2.  AVX1 and AVX2 added a few shuffles (and of course insert/extract including with memory operands).  I already had a handle on that (and an idea of the cost in uops on Haswell/Skylake) before AVX-512 CPUs were out, so the huge amount of new AVX-512 instructions were something I could learn gradually.

Comment: Other useful sources include https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/, but for understanding efficiency you really need to be looking at stuff like https://uops.info/ or Agner Fog's instruction tables to see which things cost a shuffle uop or not.  (And to understand intrinsics, look at how they compile to asm.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)).  See also other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Answering SIMD questions on SO for ~5 years (and reading other people's answers) is how I learned.

Comment: These are awesome resources, thank you so much.  I'm just starting to get into the AVX world and beginning to change the way I think.  I'll probably be posting more questions as I come across other problems that I can't surf my way through the intrinsic guide.  It's hard to know what to look for sometimes.
If you post an answer I will mark it has correct and answered.